# jquery hover can't find parent span

Tags: jquery, menu, find, parent

I'm sure that this has been covered, but there are so many jquery parent questions that sifting through them is a pretty daunting task.

I have a page with an unordered menu dropdown list like this:

```
  <ul class="topnav">
    <span><li><a href="firstitem.php">Contact</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="testlink.php">Test Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li></span>

    <span><li><a href="seconditem.php">Ministries</a>
      <ul class="subnav">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li></span>
</ul>
```

Currently, my jquery references this as such:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.topnav li a") .mouseover(function() { //When trigger is clicked...
        //Drop down the subnav on click
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast');
        $(this).parent().parent("span").hover(function() {
            //do nothing since we are already hovering over this span and menu should be dropped
        }, function(){
            //if we leave the span, slideUp the menu
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('medium');
        });
    });
});
```

The drop down works, but I can't find the span I am looking for so currently it never slides up.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Also, I'd like to do this without adding individual tag id's.  yes it would be easier, but I'm getting this code from someone else and I'd like to keep it similar.

Comment: Why are you wrapping your `<li>` with `<span>`? I don't think that's valid HTML.

Comment: I think there is no *duration* like `medium` only The strings `fast` and `slow` or use digits.[`Reference`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

Comment: I didn't know this was against validation rules, but I was doing it so that when I left the homebutton, the list items didn't immediately  slide up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

1. Don't put an `<li>` in a `<span>`. It breaks html validation rules and can cause issues.
2. The reason slideup does not work is because it is in a new function, meaning the scope of `this` has changed.

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.topnav li a") .mouseover(function() { //When trigger is clicked...
        //Drop down the subnav on click
        var $ul = $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav");
        $ul.slideDown('fast');
        $(this).parent().parent("span").hover(function() {
        //do nothing since we are already hovering over this span and menu should be dropped
        }, function(){
            //if we leave the span, slideUp the menu
            $ul.slideUp('medium');
        });
    });
});
```

This should work better for you.

Comment: thanks for fixing my markup, not sure why it came out so awful.

Comment: Except it [does work](http://jsfiddle.net/mQXRb/) (as posted by the OP), it's just not setup on page load. Mouseover from the top of the list down. At least in FF4, it works for me.

Comment: The way lists work in the markup is a little irritating. It was thinking it was part of the list, so treated it as text.

Comment: He said slide down works, but slide up doesn't unless I'm interpreting him incorrectly. This isn't technically the best fix, but its the simplest way to get slideup to find the right element.

Comment: It's working as best as I can tell; it does slide up/down. It's just not being triggered. See my answer. I'm not saying the OP couldn't do a better job in the code, it's just the code itself does work.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help.  I guess that it's something with the drop down box I'm creating with the CSS.  I'll select this as my answer though since it seems like the most valid.

Answer (score 1):

Use [parents(selector)](http://api.jquery.com/parents) instead of parent().

Comment: Even better, use .closest(selector) - this way you are assured you'll only get one result.. the closest parent.

Comment: @John Stickler: good point, thanks. Somehow I don't use .closest() at all so it haven't crossed my mind..

Comment: I started at parent() then used parents().  Then I found .closest() and never looked back :)

Comment: Are you sure this is what's wrong with the code (as far as the problem the OP is having)?

Answer (score 0):

The code is working, except on page load (meaning once you mouseover it, it starts to work). You should be able to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.topnav li a") .mouseover(function() { //When trigger is clicked...
        //Drop down the subnav on click
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast');
        $(this).parent().parent("span").hover(function() {
            //do nothing since we are already hovering over this span and menu should be dropped
        }, function(){
            //if we leave the span, slideUp the menu
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('medium');
        });
    });
    $("ul.subnav").slideUp('medium'); // <-- Note here, but you probably want to hide or something
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SvDAw/

Note, this was in FF4.

**NOTE**

I didn't comment on the incorrect use of a SPAN within a UL; this is probably not a good thing to do, as other note, since it's not valid (you should use LI's and OL/UL's within UL/OL's). So you might consider reordering your markup to either use classes on the LI's for each level, or embed some UL's within your parent UL (I like the first better).

Answer (score 0):

In this case $(this).parent() is the li element, $(this).parent().parenT() is the ul class="subnav" element and $(this).parent().parent().parent() is the span tag.